# Back button missing in KDE system-settings

Tags: settings, kde-plasma

In the kde system-settings there was a back button, if you clicked a category to edit, you could press back to return to the root category. Just a few minutes ago this button disappeared. I would like to get it back.

There are no buttons, tool-bars or menus. There are, in the root view, two tabs “general” and “Advanced”, then rows of icons with words under them (one for each category).

So how can I get my back button back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit heavy handed as it may have other effects, and needs use of command-line.

```
sed -i.backup -re "/State=.*/ d" ~/.kde/share/config/systemsettingsrc
```

It removes line starting `State=` from the config-file